# Where to find out database table object in simple JPA repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Boot and trying to work with JPA repository. I am trying to find out where does spring SimpleJpaRepository class save database table at runtime to perform further retrieve operation. I have below service class to retrieve user based on username. In eclipse I am trying inspect userRepository at line 9 but I don't know where I can find the values fetched from DB table by spring. I know that `User` class will have the details I am trying to find out but I want to see where these details are in `userRepository`. Any help is much appreciated.

```
package com.hellokoding.auth.service;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username); //line 9
    if (user == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);

    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
    for (Role role : user.getRoles()){
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: ```UserRepository``` interface must extend ```JpaRepository<User>``` interface. ```User``` class must have an ```@Table``` annotation specifying the table name. This stated, I don't really understand which further operations you might want to achieve with this information

Comment: You need to configure your database in the application.properties file. You can use an in-memory database (DB2) or a regular database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, ...): https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: @OlivierDepriester `UserRepository` is extending J`paRepository<User>` interface and `User` have `@Table` annotation. My table has data and I am able to connect to database. I want to see where(which object) `UserRepository` have table data. what I see is that `UserRepository` is object of `SimpleJpaRepository` but where I can see the table data.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong library. Spring Data JPA is just a frontend for JPA (most likely Hibernate). In there you want to look for implementations of the `EntityManager` interface.